# How to Duplicate a column or record when combining multiple table

Tags: sql, oracle

I don't know if the title describes my requirements. I have a table `C_Bpartner` (with `C_BPartner_ID` as a Primary Key) for employees like this:
                `name           Hiringorderno          Orderdate          C_Bpartner_ID`
                `A                  30                25/02/2002               100`
                `B                  47                13/10/2005               101`
                `D                  110               22/09/2010               105`

and other tables like emp_training:
                `C_Bpartner_ID        TrainingOrderno        Orderdate`
                `100                       46               14/05/2012`
                `100                       58               10/07/2013`
                `101                       76               22/10/2015`

and emp_penalty: 
                `C_Bpartner_ID        PenaltyOrderno         Orderdate`
                `105                       133               14/05/2012`
                `101                       153               25/03/2018`

I want the resulting table to be like:
                `name              orderno             Orderdate          C_Bpartner_ID`
                `A                  30                25/02/2012               100`
                `A                  46                14/05/2005               100`
                `A                  58                10/07/2013               100`
                `B                  47                13/10/2005               101`
                `B                  76                22/10/2015               101`
                `B                  153               25/03/2018               101`
                `D                  110               22/09/2010               105`
                `D                  133               14/05/2012               105`

so, I joined `C_BPartner` with itself and `coalesce` them, in order to get a second record for the same `C_BPartner_ID`. then tried to get the `Hiringorderno` from `C_BPartner bp` and join `C_BPartner pp` with `emp_penalty pt`(as an example) and get `PenaltyOrderno`
and combine them with `coalesce(bp.Hiringorderno,pt.PenaltyOrderno)` and do that for all other tables and for Orderdate as well. but it doesn't duplicate records. it picks the first coalesce parameter and discards the other. like this

```
coalesce(bp.name,pp.name)   coalesce(bp.Hiringorderno,pt.PenaltyOrderno)  Hiringorderno   PenaltyOrderno
          A                                         30                          30              null
          B                                         47                          47              153
```

the emp_penalty record for B is not there.

Comment: please do add a code, in your question, that you have done so far. Thanks!

Comment: already got the solution to my problem, thank anyway

Comment: I know, I asked two days ago :) You are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's other ways to do this, but I think the most clear and intuitive way is to UNION the 3 queries that you're trying to do.

```
select name, hiringorderno as orderno, orderdate, C_Bpartner_ID, 'HIRING' as ordertype, null as emp_penalty_ID
    from C_Bpartner
union all
select bp.name, trainingorderno, t.orderdate, bp.C_Bpartner_ID, 'TRAINING', null
    from emp_training t
    join C_Bpartner bp 
        on bp.C_Bpartner_ID = t.C_Bpartner_ID
union all
select bp.name, PenaltyOrderno, p.orderdate, bp.C_Bpartner_ID, 'PENALTY', p.emp_penalty_ID
    from emp_penalty p
    join C_Bpartner bp 
        on bp.C_Bpartner_ID = p.C_Bpartner_ID
;
```

Edit: I added 2 columns to show 2 common ways to differentiate the union'ed records.

One way is to add a constant string or number to each select statement - that way you can use `CASE WHEN ordertype = 'PENALTY' ...` or `WHERE ordertype = 'TRAINING'` to filter your records.

Another way, like you mentioned, is to fill in a column for one of the selects, like emp_penalty_id, but set it to `null` for the other select statements.

All the select statements being unioned together need to have the same number of columns, with compatible types. The first select statement defines the column names and types for the rest, which is why I didn't need to add column aliases to the second and third selects.

Comment: it works very well, but when I want to insert other tables Primary key, in order to specify whether this `orderno` is for penalty, training or else, through (not null IDs). like in 3rd select, added, `p.emp_penalty_ID` (if not null, then its penalty). but it gave me this error
`ORA-01789: query block has incorrect number of result columns`
how to avoid this, or is there another way for doing this

Comment: Yeah, that's a common issue. I edited my answer to add two different ways to do that.

Comment: I solved this by adding a column in the last of each select query. like this: `select name, GCES01_AdministrativeOrderNo as orderno, GCES01_AdministrativeOrderDate as orderdate, C_Bpartner_ID, TO_CHAR('Hiring') from C_Bpartner`, in next select query, `TO_CHAR(`Penalty')`

Comment: locking to your query, I noticed I don't need TO_CHAR part.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to union 3 queries:

```
SQL> with
  2  c_bpartner (name, hiringorderno, orderdate, c_bpartner_id) as
  3    (select 'A', 30, date '2002-02-25', 100 from dual union all
  4     select 'B', 47, date '2005-10-13', 101 from dual union all
  5     select 'D', 110,date '2010-09-22', 105 from dual
  6    ),
  7  emp_training(c_bpartner_id, trainingorderno, orderdate) as
  8    (select 100, 46, date '2012-05-14' from dual union all
  9     select 100, 58, date '2013-07-10' from dual union all
 10     select 101, 76, date '2015-10-22' from dual
 11    ),
 12  emp_penalty (c_bpartner_id, penaltyorderno, orderdate) as
 13    (select 105, 133, date '2012-05-14' from dual union all
 14     select 101, 153, date '2018-03-25' from dual
 15    )
 16  select c.name, c.hiringorderno as orderno, c.orderdate, c.c_bpartner_id
 17  from c_bpartner c
 18  union all
 19  select c.name, t.trainingorderno, t.orderdate, t.c_bpartner_id
 20  from c_bpartner c join emp_training t on t.c_bpartner_id = c.c_bpartner_id
 21  union all
 22  select c.name, p.penaltyorderno, p.orderdate, p.c_bpartner_id
 23  from c_bpartner c join emp_penalty p on p.c_bpartner_id = c.c_bpartner_id
 24  order by 1, 2;

N    ORDERNO ORDERDATE  C_BPARTNER_ID
- ---------- ---------- -------------
A         30 25/02/2002           100
A         46 14/05/2012           100
A         58 10/07/2013           100
B         47 13/10/2005           101
B         76 22/10/2015           101
B        153 25/03/2018           101
D        110 22/09/2010           105
D        133 14/05/2012           105

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: this is not useful for me, because my tables are not record limited, it not only three or columns. there is always a new record

Comment: Too bad. But, it does **exactly** what you asked and returns result you wanted. Besides, I don't understand what "because etc." means.

Comment: I meant this code part `select 'A', 30, date '2002-02-25', 100 from dual union all
  4     select 'B', 47, date '2005-10-13', 101 from dual union all
  5     select 'D', 110,date '2010-09-22', 105 from dual`. I cannot insert all records manually. there more than 1000 records in these tables

Comment: Nobody expects you to enter that *manually*. If you provided test case (CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO sample data), I wouldn't have to make my own test case using CTE (Common Table Expression, a.k.a. WITH factoring clause). You already have that data. Code that is useful for you begins at line #16 in my example.

Comment: OH!, in this case, that makes sense. Anyway, the second answer(kfinity answer) worked for me, which is the same as yours from line #16. but i had one issue with it. can you read my comment in second answer, please.

Comment: It usually happens when you use UNION of 2 SELECT statements, but they don't have the same number of columns.